# Reference request: Behavior of power series at endpoints

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

I would like to find a calculus book (or a book on real analysis or advanced calculus) which has the following result:

If a power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ has a radius of convergence $r>0$, and the power series diverges at one of the endpoints, then
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_{n}x^{n-1}$ also diverges at that endpoint.

(I'm not asking for a proof, just a reference.)

Comment: If you look at it from the other side, all you need is a book that treats Dirchlet's test.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer You are certainly right about this (as usual), but I am looking for a book that states this result explicitly.

Comment: Can't help with that, I'm afraid, sorry.

Comment: I found it here (beginning of page 4): http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/powertheorems.pdf
Perhaps it can be found in one of the books listed as literature (I guess it has to be a book, not a link).

Comment: @Poppy I did find this result online, but (as you say) I'm trying to find a calculus book which has this result. [This is a good reference, though.]

Comment: Found it, finally. Author: Mark I︠A︡kovlevich Vygodskiĭ
Book: Mathematical handbook: higher mathematics
Page: 585
I have a Russian version, it's on page 579.

Comment: But it's just a Remark, there is no proof.

Comment: @Poppy Maybe you could post this as an answer.  I'm hoping to find a more accessible reference, but at least this is a book that has the statement of the result.

Comment: Ok, I can post it in two days if there isn't a better result. Perhaps it's better if there is 0 answers to your question. Goodluck :)

Comment: @Poppy Thanks - this sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this, a proof of it, and an in depth exploration of the behavior of power series at their boundaries in E.C. Titchmarsh's "Theory of Functions."